# Find a nonabelian subgroup of order $10$ in $D_{15}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Find a nonabelian subgroup of order $10$ in $D_{15}$.

I know that I have to show that it has a reflection. How could I prove that if the subgroup contains all rotations, it wouldn't be a subgroup?

Comment: There is something odd about the phrasing of this question. A subgroup is never empty, and in this case it even has to have a specified order, so mentioning non-empty seems strange.

Comment: @Tobias sorry, fixed it, had a brain fart

Comment: @Tobias: Maybe I am wrong, but I have seen $D_{2n}$ in my texts.  $D_{15}$??

Comment: @BabakSorouh its 15, is that unusual?

Comment: @user5208: Presumably $D_{15}$ means the dihedral group of order $30$?

Comment: @BabakSorouh The notation varies. Sometimes, the index is the order, sometimes half the order (the degree as a permutation group in the natural way).

Comment: @BabakSorouh in my text it translates to having order 30

Comment: @ChrisEagle yes

Comment: Well, good thing [there is only one](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_small_groups#List_of_small_non-abelian_groups), find $\mathbb{Z}_5$ and the idempotent elements.

Comment: @NickKidman Groups don't have idempotent elements.

Comment: @Nick Kidman: when you say there is only one, you mean that there is only one isomorphism class of nonabelian groups of order 10 - that is, $D_5$ in the notation of the question. It is *not* true that $D_{15}$ has a unique nonabelian subgroup of order 10. It has three, all conjugate.

Comment: I can't believe people haven't agreed on $D_n$ instead of $D_{2n}$.  We don't call the symmetric groups $S_1$, $S_2$, $S_6$, $S_{24}$, etc.  /rant

Comment: @DerekHolt: Well yes, I wasn't implying anything or commenting further on it. I saw the possibility but it doesn't matter. The question asks to find one, and once he got one of them the task's done. But I don't want to say it should be just about solving a given task, more information is good.

Comment: @Tobias: I think the opposite is the case: every group has one. But yeah, you're essentially right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We are working on $$D_{2\times 15}=\langle \alpha,\beta\mid\alpha^{15}=\beta^2=(\alpha\beta)^2=1\rangle$$ We can also consider $\alpha,\beta$ as follows:

$$\alpha=(1,2,...15),~\beta=\begin{pmatrix}
  1 & 2 & 3 & 4& ~...~14& 15\\
  1 & 15 & 14 & 13& ~...~3& 2\\
\end{pmatrix}$$

Clearly the only power of $\alpha$ of order $5$ is $\alpha^3$. Now set $H=\langle\alpha^3\rangle$. Using the relation of the group we can show that $H$ is a normal subgroup. NOe we take $H\langle\beta\rangle$.

Comment: Nice approach to the problem! +1

Comment: If you mean why upvotes aren't increasing my rep: once you've earned 200 points from upvotes, you cap for the day (the upvotes still appear as an additional vote, but you can earn at most 200 points from upvotes).You can earn unlimited points per day from "accepts". The new day starts in roughly 8 hours. When rep for the day new day returns to "zero"

Comment: Wait for the new day! ;-)

Comment: In roughly 8 hours (a little less than that now), the new day starts for everyone at stackexchange.com

Answer (score 4):

$D_{15}$ is the symmetries of a regular 15-gon. "Extend" a regular pentagon in Euclidean plane to a regular 15-gon so that any symmetry of the pentagon is in $D_{15}$. So, $D_{15}$ contains a copy of $D_5$.

Answer (score 3):

$D_{15} = \left<a,b | a^{15}=1, b^2=1, bab=a^{-1} \right>$

Consider the subgroup generated by $a^3$ and $b$.